# Kivy widget is hidden under Windows titlebar

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have been trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe app in Kivy. I started by laying out the UI, and found that the top section is hidden under the Windows title bar. I have tried to search around for an answer in the Kivy docs, on StackOverflow, etc. but had no luck.

Here's a screenshot for reference: [Titlebar covering up part of Kivy app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBBcv.png)

.kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn0'
                icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn1'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Group1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn2'
    TicTacToeGrid:

<GridEntry>:
    font_size: self.height
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

<TicTacToeGrid>:
    cols: 3
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.149, 0.102, 0.051, 1.0
        Line:
            points: self.width/3, self.center_y - (self.height * 0.45), self.width/3, self.center_y + (self.height * 0.45)
            width: 2
        Line:
            points: self.width*2/3, self.center_y - (self.height * 0.45), self.width*2/3, self.center_y + (self.height * 0.45)
            width: 2

        Line:
            points: self.center_x - (self.width * 0.45), self.height/3, self.center_x + (self.width * 0.45), self.height/3
            width: 2
        Line:
            points: self.center_x - (self.width * 0.45), self.height*2/3, self.center_x + (self.width * 0.45), self.height*2/3
            width: 2
```

.py file

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class GridEntry(Button):
    coords = ListProperty([0, 0])


class TicTacToeGrid(GridLayout):
    '''Kivy widget for the tic-tac-toe board'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TicTacToeGrid, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(3):
                grid_entry = GridEntry(
                    coords=(row, column))
                grid_entry.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
                self.add_widget(grid_entry)

    def button_pressed(self, button):
        '''Print output just to see what's going on'''
        print('{} button clicked!'.format(button.coords))


class TicTacToeApp(App):
    '''Tic-tac-toe app using Kivy'''

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0.688, 0.664, 0.640, 1)
        return self.root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TicTacToeApp().run()
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Brendan I can not reproduce it. I tested your code on Windows 10 with kivy 1.10.0 and kivy 1.9.1 and on Arch Linux (KDE) with kivy 1.10.0 and the app looks good.

Comment: It also works for me, windows 10 kivy 1.9.1

Comment: I found switching to my dGPU rather than integrated graphics solved the issue. How should I go about troubleshooting this? I would like it to work regardless of which graphics card it is using...

Comment: I found the same problem on Dell XP 15 with Windows 10 x64.

Comment: @rlat That's strange, I'm using an XPS 15 as well.

Comment: I have exact same problem here, Windows 10 64 bits, Samsung Odyssey i7, in other computer with Windows 7 64 bits I don't have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem recently on my dell XPS 15. Updating the drivers for the integrated graphics processor through device manager resolved it on my set up, have you tried that?

Comment: I had the same problem here, updated my integrated graphics processor just as you say and solved my problem too, thanks a lot !!!